# Tell nginx to silently ignore missing files

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

I am looking for a way to tell nginx to use a particular certificate if available, otherwise ignore silently (i.e. don't crash)

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name myapp.io;

    ssl_certificate           /path/to/my/certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key       /path/to/my/certificate.key;
}
```

Currently this crashes with

```
2018/10/29 12:25:16 [emerg] 18978#0: BIO_new_file("path/to/my/certificate.cer") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('path/to/my/certificate.cer','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

What I am trying to achieve is have the server running, such that certbot can generate a certificate for me and subsequently add it, but currently the server crashes when it cannot find a file, which to me is fragile.

Comment: Any luck with the issue? Have the same one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to achieve what you want. Instead generate & use self signed certificates for ssl or configure nginx for port 80 only until you get CA signed certs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DNS verification for you certificate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).